# Is this correct even if I get two different answers for slope-intercept form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, slope

Writing an Equation for a Linear Function Given Two Points

If $f$ is a linear function, with $f(3)=−2$, and $f(8)=1$, find an equation for the function in slope-intercept form.

We can write the given points using coordinates.
\begin{align*}
f(3) & = −2 \to (3,−2)\\
f(8) & = 1 \to (8,1)
\end{align*}

We can then use the points to calculate the slope.

\begin{align*}
m & = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}\\
  & = \frac{1 - (-2)}{8 - 3}\\
  & = \frac{3}{5}
\end{align*}

Substitute the slope and the coordinates of ONE OF THE POINTS into the point-slope form.

*The book decided to use $(3, -2)$ whereas I decided to use $(8, 1)$.

\begin{align*}
y - y_1 & = m(x - x_1)\\
y - (-2) & = \frac{3}{5}(x - 3)
\end{align*}

The book goes further in their example.

We can use algebra to rewrite the equation in the slope-intercept form.

\begin{align*}
y + 2 & = \frac{3}{5}(x - 3)\\
y + 2 & = \frac{3}{5}x - \frac{9}{5}\\
y & = \frac{3}{5}x - \frac{19}{5}
\end{align*}

The points I chose to use $(8, 1)$, which then gave me the answer

\begin{align*}
y - 1 & = \frac{3}{5}(x - 8)\\
y & = \frac{3}{5}x - 5
\end{align*}

Because of choosing different points I get what seems a different slope-intercept even when it states "Substitute the slope and the coordinates of ONE OF THE POINTS into the point-slope form.". Is this ok?

Comment: How did you get $-5$ in your answer?  Please check/show your arithmetic.

Comment: Short answer, no, you should always get the same $y$-intercept.  You have an arithmetic error.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter which point one picks, you will get the same solution.

$$y-1=\frac35 \left( x-8\right)$$

$$y=\frac35x - \frac{24}5+1=\frac35x-\frac{24-5}{5}=\frac35x-\frac{19}{5}$$

which is consistent with the other solution.